# How can I modify Green Tron to better combat Aggro Spirits?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I realise this post might be broad, but I’m struggling to find cards to beat an Aggro spirit deck. I’m playing green tron and my opponent has a spirit deck which with the flyers is taking me down too much by the time I get my tron lands down.

Are there any modern cards that will help destroy a spirit deck aiming to get many Spirits down which boost each other?

Or if Tron isn’t the right deck, what decks work well vs a spirit deck?

My deck is as follows

> #### Lands
>
> - [Urza’s mine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220947) x4
> - [Urza’s Power Plant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=urza%27s%20power%20plant) x4
> - [Urza Tower](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220957) x 4
> - [Basic land Forest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443154)  x4
>
> #### Artifacts
>
> - [Expedition Map](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397742) x4
> - [Planar Bridge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=423838)  x2
> - [Treasure map](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=treasure%20map) x 1
> - [Oblivion Stone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247338) x 4
> - [Chromatic Star](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=135279) x4
> - [Mana Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=mana%20vault) x1
>
> #### Planeswalker
>
> - [Karn, scion of Urza](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=442889) x1
>
> #### Sorceries
>
> - [All is Dust](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=456597) x1
> - [Sylvan Scrying](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=402065) x 4
> - [Ancient Stirrings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=442148) x4
>
> #### Instants
>
> - [Natures Claim](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=198357) x3
> - [Haze of Pollen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426873) x2
> - [Commencement of Festivities](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=417721) x2
> - [Swell of growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=402064) x1
> - [Crop Rotation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=12432) x1
>
> #### Creatures
>
> - [Deceiver of form](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deceiver%20of%20Form) x2
> - [End Bringer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=407513) x2
> - [Conduit of Ruin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401847) x2
> - [It That Betrays](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=it%20that%20betrays) x2
> - [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106537) x2
> - [Kozilek, the Great Distortion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=407514) x1
> - [Emrakul, the Promised End](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=414295) x1
> - [Emrakul, the Aeons Torn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397905)x1
>
> #### Sideboard
>
> - [Skittering Invasion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=193614) x2
> - [Wrapping Wail](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=warping%20wail) x2
> - [Titan’s Presence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=402073) x 4
> - [Not of This World](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=198296) x2
> - [Loxodon warhammer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=loxodon%20warhammer) x2
> - [Endbringer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=407513) x1
> - [Conduit of Ruin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401847) x1
> - [Artisan of Kozilek](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=456598) x1

Comment: By the way, I recently put in the instances to try slow him down

Comment: Best of three normally, we do sideboard.. but I hardly sideboard because I don’t have anything in my side board to help me out vs his spirits.. I’ll add my sideboard to the list

Comment: Without knowing much about deck building, my immediate thought was [Hurricane](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=129885).

Comment: Closest modern legal card I can think of is scapeshift, but at 4 times the cost may not be worthwhile

Comment: Mana Vault isn't legal in anything but Vintage and Commander.  If you're playing Vintage, your deck is missing some power 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: not an expert on Modern. The following comes from my understanding of other formats & my reading of Modern strategy articles.

As Hall-of-Famer [Paulo Vitor Damo Da Rosa wrote](https://www.channelfireball.com/articles/is-bant-spirits-replacing-humans-as-the-best-tribal-deck-in-modern/), Tron is slightly favoured against spirits, especially pre-board. However, your build of Tron is subpar because your payoff cards are less than ideal. Cards like [It That Betrays](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIt%20That%20Betrays%5d) cost so much mana to cast, doesn't immediately impact the board, and even if you survive to attack with it, you might not win (opponent can sacrifice 2 lands and swing back for lethal). You're also running cards like Nature's Claim in the maindeck, which is completely dead against spirits (this is the reason why Nature's Claim is a sideboard card: it's dead against too many strategies; you only bring it in when it's good). As a result, a complete answer would be very big indeed since it'd involve a complete rebuilding of your deck. I'll refer you instead to these two primers on [G/X Tron](https://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/the-game/modern/established-modern/big-mana/220174-gx-tron) and [Eldrazi Tron](https://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/the-game/modern/established-modern/big-mana/769015-colorless-eldrazi-tron) on MTG Salvation. Note they are different decks and play out differently - you should choose one and build that way, not try to be both.

For cards themselves I'll mention only these, because they're the most critical to the matchup when both decks are well-built.

[Oblivion Stone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOblivion%20Stone%5d): I see you're already running four, so you should know how good they are.

[Wurmcoil Engine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWurmcoil%20Engine%5d): gaining 6 life means they can't kill you, and it's too powerful for them to trade with. They basically need to have [Path to Exile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPath%20to%20Exile%5d) or lose.

[Ugin, the Spirit Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUgin%2c%20the%20Spirit%20Dragon%5d): Ugin's second ability is a one-sided sweeper against Spirits.

[Walking Ballista](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWalking%20Ballista%5d): this lets you snipe off all their X/1's easily and still maybe have a body left over. Remember it also instantly kills [Phantasmal Image](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPhantasmal%20Image%5d).

**Edit**: remembered that spirits runs [Aether Vial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAether%20Vial%5d), so maindeck Nature's Claim aren't dead. However, it's still not worth it. They will have hands which don't contain Vial, and it's not like you auto-win if they don't have Vial either. Nature's Claim is for fighting the likes of [Stony Silence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStony%20Silence%5d) (which, if it resolves, almost paralyzes you) and Affinty; the sideboard is the place for these narrow hate cards, not the maindeck.

Comment: Thanks Allure, I don't think I'm far off the G/X Tron I have all the Core cards except for Karn Liberated. I'll get rid of It That Betrays and put some wurmcoil Engine and Walking blister in.. Some great directions to go with there thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Two cards you are already running 1x that you may want more of vs Spirits in particular:

- [Endbringer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEndbringer%5d): for pinging small spirits (and Noble Hierarch)
- [All is Dust](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAll%20is%20Dust%5d): for one-sided board wipes

Other cards that often show up in Tron that you may want to consider:

- [World Breaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorld%20Breaker%5d): reach and removal; you already have the green to cast it.
- [Ulamog, the Ceaseless Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlamog%2c%20the%20Ceaseless%20Hunger%5d): a finisher with a good effect on cast
- [Ugin, the Spirit Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUgin%2c%20the%20Spirit%20Dragon%5d): either recurring removal or spot removal and a damage sink
- [Wurmcoil Engine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWurmcoil%20Engine%5d): a beater that gains you life

Comment: I don't think aggro spirits is Faeries. Aggro spirits is spirits: it uses cards like Selfless Spirit, Drogskul Captain, Supreme Phantom, Geist of Saint Traft ...