# Sideboard for Modern U/G infect against Gideon

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-modern

I'm playing Modern U/G Infect ([example list](http://www.mtgtop8.com/event?e=21382&d=343028&f=MO)). I need help dealing with [Gideon of the Trials](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%20of%20the%20Trials%5d) and [Gideon, Ally of Zendikar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20Ally%20of%20Zendikar%5d). The first Gideon's emblem means I need to attack twice to win, and his +1 ability also stops me from doing damage if I have only a single infector out. The second Gideon keeps the first Gideon's emblem active, plus makes an endless stream of blockers for my attackers. What can I do about these cards?

Comment: You would probably be better served asking this question on one of the many MTG online communities.  MTGSalvation is probably the one I would recommend for this type of question.

Comment: Voting to reopen because this is hardly too broad to answer. Gideon is a single card. If this is too broad, questions like https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44347/how-can-i-modify-green-tron-to-better-combat-aggro-spirits would be impossible to answer. It's true that better answers can be gotten elsewhere, but if it's within the scope, why not here too?

Comment: @Allure, I think the problem is that "u/g infect" is rather vague for deck building advice. I'm not an expert, but I doubt that there's only one u/g budget infect deck in existence, and they will have different sideboard needs. A decklist would help a lot

Comment: @ArcanistLupus U/G Infect is a well-known Modern deck; it's the standard colors used by Infect decks. The deck was top tier once, before Gitaxian Probe was banned. Knowing the archetype is sufficient to guess most of the cards. Here's a recent list. http://www.mtgtop8.com/event?e=21382&d=343028&f=MO The gameplan is to stick an infect creature, cast lots of pump spells, and kill in one swing. Gideon of the Trials interacts with this plan because the emblem means you first have to kill your opponent (takes lots of pump spells), and then kill Gideon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is to ignore it. Gideon of the Trials is not a common card in Modern, and with the format as wide as it is, dedicating sideboard slots to combating this rare threat is not a good idea. If you can't ignore Gideon (maybe there's someone who consistently plays Gideon tribal at your local store), then these cards might help:

- [Echoing Truth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEchoing%20Truth%5d) is a catch-all against every hate card, from Gideon to [Chalice of the Void](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChalice%20of%20the%20Void%5d) on 1.
- [Spell Pierce](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpell%20Pierce%5d) can stop Gideon from resolving in the first place, which is probably your best bet, since killing Gideon after it's entered play will be very hard. Spell Pierce also interacts with [Path to Exile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPath%20to%20Exile%5d) (which any deck playing Gideon is likely to have). Infect is fast enough that the opponent is not likely to get to five mana to pay for it.
- [Sorcerous Spyglass](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSorcerous%20Spyglass%5d) is the next card that comes to mind. As long as you cast Spyglass before Gideon enters play, he does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some common sideboard cards that are effective here.

Spell Pierce can keep Gideons off the field for just 1 mana. Gideons cost a lot of mana (for modern), so they should rarely be able to pay. It can also deal with removal and nasty sideboard cards like Solemnity

Echoing Truth can help manage a resolved Gideon. It can remove a Gideon from the field to turn off his emblem and can remove all the Knight Ally tokens at once (though note that both Inkmoth Nexus and Blighted Agent go around them anyways). It can also handle infect hosers like Solemnity or Melira.

Spellskite is probably the best way to deal with Gideon of the Trials's +1. It also deals with Path to Exile, a common sight in decks that play Gideon.